# XRDP Problem Ubuntu 14.04.1

Tags: 14.04, networking, xrdp

I have 14.04.1 installed on a laptop in the basement with no working display. The screen had a crack which made the initial install difficult and now the backlight went so short of lugging a monitor to it there is no way to locally view anything.

My goal is to turn this computer into a DHCP/DNS/Mail/Backup system for my home network. I do have SSH functional so I can SSH in from my other computers, I followed the guide at http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=5305 on how to install XRDP but when I try to connect using Remmenia remote desktop client from 192.168.1.110 to 192.168.1.104 it connects then exists out. I do not see any error messages and I do briefly get a dekstop but it's devoid of any icons.

Answer (score 0):

To investigate a little bit further, I would try to see if the problem is related to the xRDP installation or related to the remmina client.

We had some issues with the remmina client in the past.  I would suggest you to try to connect to your remote ubuntu machine using either mstsc.exe from a Windows machine or install on your linux machine next to remmina another remote desktop client.   You can install rdesktop or xfreerdp client (they are command line based client).  for the rdesktop, there is a basic gui interface called grdesktop.

If you can connect through these clients, the problem is remmina. if you cannot, xRDP might be the problem and you can start looking into the logs (in /var/logs/xrdp *  and in your ~/.xsession file to see  any connection issue

Hope this help